# Python: How do you login to a page and view the resulting page in a browser?

Tags: python, authentication

I've been googling around for quite some time now and can't seem to get this to work. A lot of my searches have pointed me to finding similar problems but they all seem to be related to cookie grabbing/storing. I think I've set that up properly, but when I try to open the 'hidden' page, it keeps bringing me back to the login page saying my session has expired.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, webbrowser

username = 'userhere'
password = 'passwordhere'
url = 'http://example.com'
webbrowser.open(url, new=1, autoraise=1)
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open('http://example.com', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://example.com/afterlogin')
print resp
webbrowser.open(url, new=1, autoraise=1)
```

Comment: Please post the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: you will need to provide more details. Code would help.

Answer (score 4):

First off, when doing cookie-based authentication, you need to have a [`CookieJar`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar) to store your cookies in, much in the same way that your browser stores its cookies a place where it can find them again.

After opening a login-page through python, and saving the cookie from a successful login, you should use the [`MozillaCookieJar`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.MozillaCookieJar) to pass the python created cookies to a format a firefox browser can parse. Firefox 3.x no longer uses the cookie format that MozillaCookieJar produces, and I have not been able to find viable alternatives.

If all you need to do is to retrieve specific (in advance known format formatted) data, then I suggest you keep all your HTTP interactions within python. It is much easier, and you don't have to rely on specific browsers being available. If it is absolutely necessary to show stuff in a browser, you could render the so-called 'hidden' page through urllib2 (which incidentally integrates very nicely with cookielib), save the html to a temporary file and pass this to the [`webbrowser.open`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html?highlight=webbrowser#webbrowser.open) which will then render that specific page. Further redirects are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've generally used the [mechanize library](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to handle stuff like this. That doesn't answer your question about why your existing code isn't working, but it's something else to play with.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code calls:

```
opener.open('http://example.com', login_data)
```

but throws away the response. I would look at this response to see if it says "Bad password" or "I only accept IE" or similar.